# Calculus II: Limit exercise

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm currently studying for my Calc exam and I came across this exercise.

The problem is to find the values for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ so that the following limit exists:

$$ \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{xy}{ax^2+bxy+cy^2} $$

Along the path $y=kx$, the expression becomes:
$$ \lim_{(x,kx) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{kx^2}{ax^2+kbx^2+k^2cx^2} $$$$ \lim_{(x,kx) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{k}{a+kb+k^2c}$$

If we evaluate the limit along the path where $k=0$ or $k=1$, we get $0$ and $\frac{1}{a+b+c}$ respectively. because the second one can never become zero for any value of $a,b,c$, I would conclude that the limit doesn't exist, but I don't think that's the correct answer, so I'm probably doing something wrong.

Some help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You started with good directions, but not using the right arguments.

In particular, if $a=c=0$ the limit exists and is equal to $1/b$ providing that $b \neq 0$. Let's prove that the limit exists if and only if $a=c=0$ and $b \neq 0$ and that its value is $1/b$ in that case.

Along the path $ y=kx$ you have indeed

$$f(x,y) = \frac{k}{a+kb+k^2c}$$ for $x \neq 0$ where

$$f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{ax^2+bxy+cy^2}.$$

For the limit to exist, $\frac{k}{a+kb+k^2c}$ has to be independent of $k$ which implies $a=c=0$ and if such we must have $b\neq 0$ in order for $f$ to be properly defined around $(0,0)$. If those conditions are fulfilled, it is easy to verify that $f$ is constant and equal to $1/b$ and therefore the limit exuists and is equal to $1/b$.